# what is magic of Scala Array.apply

Tags: arrays, scala, reflection, types, scala-2.10

From array.scala of scala-2.10.4, The **Array** is defined as

```
final class Array[T](_length: Int) extends java.io.Serializable with java.lang.Cloneable {    
  /** The length of the array */
  def length: Int = throw new Error()
  def apply(i: Int): T = throw new Error()
  def update(i: Int, x: T) { throw new Error() }
  override def clone(): Array[T] = throw new Error()
}
```

Please note, the apply method will throw an exception! And for the accompany object Arrry, I find the following codes:

```
  def apply[T: ClassTag](xs: T*): Array[T] = {
    val array = new Array[T](xs.length)
    var i = 0
    for (x <- xs.iterator) { array(i) = x; i += 1 }
    array
  }
```

I know there is an implicit parameter which is **ClassTag[T]**, what make me surprised is how

> new Array[T] (xs.length)

is compiled. By decompiling the Array.class, I find that line is translated to :

```
public <T> Object apply(Seq<T> xs, ClassTag<T> evidence$2)
{
    // evidence$2 is implicit parameter
    Object array = evidence$2.newArray(xs.length());
    ...  
}
```

I am really confused by this kind of translation, what is the rule under the hood?

Thanks
Chang

Comment: [`ClassTag[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag) has a method `newArray` which creates a new `Array[T]`

Comment: @PeterNeyens, I know there is a newArray method, but i don't know why newArray  is picked by compile

Comment: Quoting the first line of [`Manifest[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest) (a subclass of `ClassTag[T]`): "_Its supported use is to give access to the erasure of the type as a Class instance, as is necessary for the creation of native Arrays if the class is not known at compile time._"

Comment: @PeterNeyens what i want know is how implicit paramter is used?  if you look at  def apply[T: ClassTag](xs: T*): Array[T],  I don't find any syntax rule can enable translating *new 
A

Comment: @PeterNeyens  please look at * val array = new Array[T](xs.length) *, which syntax rule is applied, so that we can translate new Array[T] into evidence$2.newArray

Comment: Array in Scala is heavily optimized/modified by the compiler. The code in Array.scala or decompiled class is more or less just for reference. Don't take it as is

Answer (score 5):

The Scala `Array` Class is just a fake wrapper for the runtime so you can use arrays in Scala. You're probably confused because those methods on the `Array` class throw exceptions. The reason they did this is so that if you actually end up using the fake class it blows up since really it should be using the java runtime array, which does not have a proper container class like Scala. You can see how the [compiler handles it here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/70f0b1ded880ec9b3a9478d02f1898fcfeee230c/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeIdiomatic.scala#L355-L377). When your using arrays in Scala you're probably also using some implicits from predef like `ArrayOps` and `WrappedArray` for extra helper methods.

**TLDR**: Scala compiler magic makes arrays work with the java runtime under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

On the JVM arrays are exempt from type-erasure, e.g. at runtime instead of `Array[_]` there is a difference between `Array[Int]`, `Array[String]` and `Array[AnyRef]` for example. Unlike Java, Scala can handle this mostly transparently, so

```
class Foo {
  val foo = new Array[Int](123)
}
```

has a direct byte-code invocation for creating the integer array, whereas

```
class Bar[A](implicit ev: reflect.ClassTag[A]) {
  val bar = new Array[A](123)
}
```

is solved by using the implicit type evidence parameter of type `ClassTag[A]` so that at runtime the JVM can still create the correct array. This is translated into the call you saw, `ev.newArray(123)`.

Comment: As far as I know, to refer such evidence  parameter, we need something like this:  val tag = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]; tag.newArray(123).  However, in this situation, new Array[T] is directly translated to ev.newArray(123). I can't believe scala compile does some magic thing when they met new Array[T]

Comment: In other words, the answer to the question in the title "what is magic of Scala `Array.apply`" is "it really *is* magic".