# How Scala Array apply method returns the value at the index when the implementation is simply throw new error

Tags: scala

I scratched my head a lot before posting.

```
object ScalaPractice extends App {
  val nums = Array("zero","one","two")
  print(nums.apply(0))
}
```

The implementation of the `apply` method from `print(nums.apply(0))` is simply from Array class as below:

```
def apply(i: Int): T = throw new Error()
```

I even tried to debug, but, it does not go in this method (though the IDE sends me when I try to open the implementation).

This is really confusing, how the element at a particular index is fetched here?

Comment: "The Scala Array Class is just a fake wrapper for the runtime so you can use arrays in Scala." -> Possible duplicate of [what is magic of Scala Array.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001175/what-is-magic-of-scala-array-apply)

Comment: This is not duplicate @RyanTheLeach. The question posted by you in this comment is the Array companion object's apply method while array creation. My question is related to how a value from a particular index is fetched! Please check the complete question.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but it has something to do with this function in the compiler. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4089618bc11365179fc9142c5fe8e62404e9ce18/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L152

Comment: @RyanTheLeach You did not misunderstand; your linked question is clearly about all the array magic. Nice of you to follow up with more source code links. Array is mentioned as special to the backend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076047/what-types-are-special-to-the-scala-compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [what-is-magic-of-scala-array-apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001175/what-is-magic-of-scala-array-apply) The Scala compiler interjects, and that the Scala runtime has several class definitions that solely exist to provide something to link to, that is otherwise handled by compiler magic.

The Scala compiler, when it creates [bytecode for Apply methods](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4089618bc11365179fc9142c5fe8e62404e9ce18/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L509) that it   [determines is an accessor for type array](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4089618bc11365179fc9142c5fe8e62404e9ce18/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L209): 
Will [generate jvm bytecode for interacting with arrays directly](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4089618bc11365179fc9142c5fe8e62404e9ce18/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L152).